# docker on mac + docker-machine. can't ctrl+c

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm running what I believe to be the latest version of docker and docker-machine on Mac via homebrew (vmware backend for docker machine) and I'm having trouble using `ctrl+c` to exit containers which have been started in `-it` mode.

```
[ 2016-03-23 18:56:33 | oliver@mbp ]  ( ~/docker/volumes )
556 $ docker -v
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd
[ 2016-03-23 18:56:52 | oliver@mbp ]  ( ~/docker/volumes )
557 $ docker-machine -v
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
[ 2016-03-23 18:56:57 | oliver@mbp ]  ( ~/docker/volumes )
558 $ docker run -it ubuntu:latest tail -f /var/log/dmesg
(Nothing has been logged yet.)
^C^C^C^C^C

^C^C^Chello
ffs^C^C^C^C
```

Typing and carriage returns works, but not `ctrl+c`. The references I could find online to this issue date back a couple of years.

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or my expectations are incorrect, or something else. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: running iTerm2 on El-Capitan if that makes a difference.

Comment: Try it without the -t, you don't need a tty to tail a logfile.

Comment: Thanks for that, that worked. Need to double check what all the options mean in that case!